# How to mock resttemplate by mockito

Tags: java, mocking, resttemplate

I want to mock a resttemplate request,but it seems not work.
Here is the class that i want test:

```java
public class SomeUtil {
    public static OrderInstanceResponse doGet(String url, otherargs...) {
       //some code...
       ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestHeader, String.class, requestMap);
       //another code...
    }
}
```

Here is the Test Class:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeUtilTest {
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void doGet() {
        OrderInstanceResponse exceptResponse = OrderInstanceResponse.builder().code("123").build();
        OrderInstanceRequest request = OrderInstanceRequest.builder().userId("123").build();

        Map<String, Object> testMap = new HashMap<>(1);
        testMap.put("userId", "123");

        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.eq(String.class), Mockito.eq(testMap)))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("\"code\":\"123\"", HttpStatus.OK));

        OrderInstanceResponse actualResponse = RestTemplateUtil.doGet("123", request, "123");
        Assert.assertEquals(actualResponse.getCode(), exceptResponse.getCode());
    }
}
```

There are some errors when I run this test:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute`.

It seems that mock not work,There was a real request to "123".

How can i fix this bug?thanks

Comment: By the way, `RestTemplate` implements the `RestOperations` interface specifically to make mocking easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. 
When we need to mock a object that created by `new`, like `RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate()`, should be written like this：

```java
PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectToBeMocked.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockedObject);
```

Then add annotation `@PrepareForTest({TheClassToBeTested.class})`. Please note, the param is the class that containing the object obtained by `new`.
So, the complete code is as follows:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SomeUtil.class})
public class SomeUtilTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void doGet() {
        //......
        PowerMockito.whenNew(RestTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(restTemplate);
        //......
    }
}
```

Thanks all the friends who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `RestTemplate` instance to the RestTemplateUtil as a dependency for this to work, rather than instantiating it in the `doGet` method. Then, in the unit test pass the mock `RestTemplate` instance to the RestTemplateUtil.

```
public class SomeUtil {
    public SomeUtil(RestTemplate restTemplate) { this.restTemplate = restTemplate }
    public OrderInstanceResponse doGet(String url, otherargs...) {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.restTemplate.exchange(...
    }
}
```

Or pass RestTemplate as a parameter if you want to keep it as a static method.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried it your way but it still didn't work.I mock resttemplate like this`RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);`, and pass RestTemplate as a parameter to `doGet(RestTemplate rest, String url, ...)`. No more `URI is not absolute` errors, but the responseEntity is NULL. The return value I set is not valid.

Comment: Ok, it is now using the mock in that case, likely one of the matchers in your 'mockito.when()' doesn't match, maybe try replacing the eqs with anys and see if that works

Comment: I have found the solution and answered it below the question. Thank you again for your help :)